# Material UI Date Time Picker example

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am trying to understand the [Material UI Date Time Picker](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/).

The problem is that the given [example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yrer4) leads to errors, because the following import cannot be found:

```
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
```

I already have tried unsuccessfully to get rid of that error in several tests. My guess is that it imports a corrupt version from `npm`. Hence, I believe it must be one of the following packages within the `package.json`:

```
"date-fns": "next",
"@types/date-ioDate-fns": "latest",
"@types/date-fns": "latest",
"@date-io/date-fns": "latest"
```

Is there a way not to use `date-fns` in order to get the example up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `tslib` to your list of dependencies, as `@date-io/date-fns` has an unmet peer dependency on it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hrz3c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

---

*As of note, while this fixes the dependencies, you might likely get the following error:*

> Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n`

Sadly this is fault of `date-fns`library 2.x release and at least according to [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1440) your best bet is to downgrade to 1.3.13

*I can confirm, that downgrading to 1.3.13 did at least fix the issue on my sandbox*

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment instead

In package.json

```
"@date-io/moment": "^1.3.11"
```

In the js file:

```
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
```

and

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
   <DateTimePicker {...props}/>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

You can find more information here: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/parsing