# React - Material Date Picker Doesn't Work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The easiest thing on internet must be "date picker", but It's too hard to integrate to react.

My Code (some part of it):

```
...
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  DatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
...

const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
....

return (
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
..... (some html here)

<DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
....(some html here)
```

And it returns that:
index.js:423 Uncaught RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n

Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

index.js:1472 The above error occurred in the  component:

Comment: It looks like you can put this on codesandbox, can you do that?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805052/material-ui-date-time-picker-example

Comment: fsdfsdfdsf https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880981/14548500 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880981/14548500 dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer to this problem.

I myself have faced this problem.

@date-io v2 has some bugs

so whenever you are installing something like @date-io/date-fns

Install version 1
for @date-io/date-fns

The exact problem that you are facing
just run this -

npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.3.13

Checkout this [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1440)

Also check [this out](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation)

This links to material UI pickers page

On top they have commands for all the @date-io install commands

I hope this answers your question

Good luck!